# Can i pend IRP_MJ_WRITE and IRP_MJ_READ using FltQueueDeferredIoWorkItem?

Tags: windows, freeze, minifilter

I am writing a file system minifilter driver that will be monitoring IRP_MJ_CREATE, IRP_MJ_CLOSE, IRP_MJ_READ & IRP_MJ_WRITE operations. I have to implement it in such a way that when my pre-op callback is invoked, I need to get an input from the user program whether to allow or block the operation (for a list of selected files) for which I am planning to use FltQueueDeferredIoWorkItem and FltCompletePendedPreOperation().

I wrote a sample where my Preop callback function does the following (as a test)
- Allocates workitem
- Calls FltQueueDeferredIoWorkItem and queues it
- Sets CompletionContext to NULL
- Returns FLT_PREOP_PENDING

My deferred IO callback routine will create a record (of my custom type from non paged pool), copy the details from PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA and pass it to the Completioncontext parameter and return with status FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_WITH_CALLBACK.

This works fine if I monitor IRP_MJ_CREATE only. If I register pre and post op routines for IRP_MJ_WRITE/READ/CLOSE as well, it works only for a few seconds and later my machine freezes.

Am I not supposed to pend IO like this for IRP_MJ_WRITE/READ/CLOSE in Pre-Create routines?

Comment: It isn't clear to me whether the list of selected files is being kept in user-mode or kernel-mode.  Might your driver be intercepting operations on the pagefile?

Comment: The list of files will be kept in kernel mode. I have not added this part yet to the code. Currently my deferred IO callback routine will interpret the callback data and copy its contents to an in-memory structure in kernel non paged pool.

Comment: You cannot pend paging IOs, so you need to take care of them appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, there were two issues:

1. I was not checking the status of FltQueueDeferredIoWorkItem initially and was returning FLT_PREOP_PENDING even when queuing failed.
2. Second issue was related to Locking the user buffer before calling FltQueueDeferredIoWorkItem. It seems like the correct way of using FltQueueDeferredIoWorkItem for read/write etc is to lock the user buffer using FltLockUserBuffer before calling FltQueueDeferredIoWorkItem. I could not find this documentation in MSDN though but found couple of other links which said so. 
   Changed my Precreate routine as follows and now it works:

..
     WorkItem = FltAllocateDeferredIoWorkItem();

```
 FltLockUserBuffer(Data);

 Status = FltQueueDeferredIoWorkItem(WorkItem, Data, &FileDeferredRoutine,     DelayedWorkQueue, CompletionContext);

 if(Status==STATUS_SUCCESS)

 return FLT_PREOP_PENDING;
```

..

Comment: of course you need call `FltLockUserBuffer` because FS use usual neither i/o - so user buffer valid only in context of requested process. before access it in arbitrary process need first lock it with mdl. exactly this `FltLockUserBuffer` and do